# How to communicate between Mobx stores created with React.createContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, react-context, mobx-react

I have my useStores.ts file which has two Mobx stores initialized in the following way.

```
import StoreA from "./stores/StoreA";
import StoreB from "./stores/StoreB";

const storesContext = createContext({
       storeA: new StoreA(),
       storeB: new StoreB(),
});

export const useStores = () => useContext(storesContext);
```

So I can use these stores inside any components in the following way.

```
const { storeA } = useStores();
```

But I'm not sure how to access storeA inside storeB.

Can someone please help me with the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a `root` store that contains all other stores, and it passes itself to the child stores, so they can "go up" to the `root` store, and then to any other store.

```js
class RootStore {
  storeA = new StoreA(this)
  storeB = new StoreB(this)
}


class StoreA{
  constructor(rootStore){
    this.rootStore = rootStore
    // get to store B 
    // this.rootStore.storeB
  }
}
```

Use with `createContext`

```js
const storesContext = createContext(new RootStore());
```

Or even better, follow the [dependency injection principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and pass `child` stores to `root` store in the `RootStore` constructor.

```js
class RootStore {
  constructor(a,b){
    this.storeA = a
    this.storeB = b

    this.storeA.setRoot(this)
    this.storeB.setRoot(this)
}

const storesContext = createContext(new RootStore(new StoreA(),new StoreB());
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to achieve the same using createContext.